# How to get the ScriptManager of Master Page into Child page's code behind c# (.cs) file

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, scriptmanager

Following is the web site environment I created:

1. I have a Master page.
2. I have created a Child page from it.
3. I have placed Script Manager on the Master page.

Now I want to access that Master page's Script Manager to create a User Control dynamically in my code behind (C#) file.

How can I access Script Manager placed on master page to my child page.

Comment: Why do you need to access the ScriptManager to create a control?

Comment: I want to create UpdatePanel dynamically , so I need script manager too.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I got it, its given in ScriptManager class itself.

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
```

Comment: How to set the property of that script manager. I am getting an error when trying to set `EnablePartialRendering` to false

Comment: if it resolved your problem, please consider giving +1 to question and answer both.\

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what exactly you want here... you want to access the script manager of your master page or just the `masterpage`?

You can access the master page by 
    `Page.Master` in code behind

Or

```
using System.Web.UI;
ScriptManager ScriptManager1 = (ScriptManager)Page.Master.FindControl("ScriptManager1") 
// to access the script manager of master page
```

or

```
Page.Master.Controls.Add(Your UserControl object) 
// to add the user control in your master page
```

Comment: ScriptManager sm = (ScriptManager)Page.Master.FindControl("ScriptManager1");

Comment: I already got the answer i.e. ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page), your answer is right too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out this:

Working with ASP.NET Master Pages Programmatically
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx