# Manually trigger Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel in the page.
Inside this UpdatePanel, I have a control which has a button.
Is it possible to Manually add a postback trigger for this button (which is inside the user control) in the code behind?

Here's the sample code

```
//Page
<UpdatePanel>
  <uc1:UserControl />
</UpdatePanel>

//UserControl
<textbox></textbox>
<asp:button></asp:Button>
```

Comment: manually add a postback trigger for this updatepanel in the Page, from the control.

Comment: By default an update panel has ChildrenAsTriggers set to true.  this would mean that any control that causes a postback would go through the update panel logic (even ones in user controls).  What are you seeing happening that is causing you a problem?

Comment: As above, this should work as you describe, is it not working? If so, what's the error?

Comment: I want to add a postback trigger because inside this control there's a FileUpload control.

When I add a postback trigger to the update panel in the page, I get this error-

A control with ID 'ButtonId' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanelId'

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to register the button in your user control as a PostbackTrigger of an UpdatePanel in your *ASPX* page which contains your user control.
I have managed to write a simple web application that replicates this scenario and without further information I cannot see where you're going wrong or what the error that you're getting is, if any. It would help if you expanded on your original question e.g. by providing relevant snippets of your code. I'll try my best...

From within the user control you can register the button as a post back trigger of the update panel with the following code:

```
    public void RegisterPostbackTrigger(UpdatePanel updatePanel)
    {
        PostBackTrigger buttonTrigger = new PostBackTrigger();
        buttonTrigger.ControlID = TestButton.ClientID;
        updatePanel.Triggers.Add(buttonTrigger);
    }
```

You will then have to call the RegisterPostbackTrigger from within you page's code behind passing in you UpdatePanel's reference as an argument. MyControl refers to the UserControl

```
    MyControl.RegisterPostbackTrigger(MainUpdatePanel);
```

An alternative way of doing this, which may be relevant to your particular issue is to access the ScriptManager directly and use its RegisterPostBackControl method passing in your button as the parameter. Here's the [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601525/how-to-get-the-scriptmanager-placed-on-master-page-into-child-pages-code-behind)!

Can't really help you anymore without more information!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact I tried this before and I got this error-

A control with ID 'ButtonId' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanelId'.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you get that error when you first run the application or when you click on the button. I assume it's the former. Try registering the button in the PreRender method, it's guaranteed to have been created at this stage of the page life cycle.

        `protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //MyControl.RegisterPostbackTrigger(MainUpdatePanel);
                
            }
        }`